# Uploading a local file with copyIntoItems webservice using objective-C

Tags: objective-c, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've been using CopyIntoItems web service defined in _vti_bin/copy.asmx using Objective-C.
Code Sinppet of Objective-C. Also pasting the .Net code which is working fine. Could you let me know what could be the reason that it's not working in Objective-C.

Objective-C Code:

```
- (void)uploadDocument {
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UploadDocument" ofType:@"xml"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test2" ofType:@"txt"];
NSLog(@"path --- :%@",path);
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *base64Str = [contents base64String];

[str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"INP_SourceUrl" withString:path options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
[str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"INP_DestinationUrl" withString:@"http://sp2010/sites/dev2/DevLibrary/test2.txt" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
[str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"INP_Stream" withString:base64Str options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

NSLog(@" string :%@",str);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.30.80/_vti_bin/copy.asmx"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(unsigned long)str.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setHTTPBody:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSLog(@"connection ---- :%@",connection);
```

}

Request XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
    <CopyIntoItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <SourceUrl>/private/var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleURLTesting-bivsvxhiwvgmsqfrbzrkffzfvpdy/Build/Products/Debug/SampleURLTesting.app/Contents/Resources/test2.txt</SourceUrl>
  <DestinationUrls>
    <string>http://sp2010/sites/dev2/DevLibrary/test2.txt</string>
  </DestinationUrls>
  <Fields>
    <FieldInformation Type="Text" DisplayName="Description" InternalName="response1" Value="Ticket" />
  </Fields>
  <Stream>dXBsb2FkIHRlc3Q=</Stream>
</CopyIntoItems>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
    <CopyIntoItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <CopyIntoItemsResult>0</CopyIntoItemsResult>
    <Results>
    <CopyResult ErrorCode="DestinationInvalid" ErrorMessage="The Copy web service method must be called on the same domain that contains the destination url." DestinationUrl="http://sp2010/sites/dev2/DevLibrary/test2.txt" />
    </Results>
    </CopyIntoItemsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

.Net Code:

```
    string webUrl = "http://sp2010/";
    WebReference.Copy copyService = new WebReference.Copy();
    copyService.Url = webUrl + "/_vti_bin/copy.asmx";
    copyService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sharepoint", "Password!", "lab");
    //Declare and initiates the Copy WebService members for uploading
    string sourceUrl = @"d:\test1.txt";            
    string[] destinationUrl = { "http://sp2010/sites/dev2/DevLibrary/test1.txt" };
    WebReference.CopyResult cResult1 = new WebReference.CopyResult();
    WebReference.CopyResult cResult2 = new WebReference.CopyResult();
    WebReference.CopyResult[] cResultArray = { cResult1, cResult2 };
    WebReference.FieldInformation fFiledInfo = new WebReference.FieldInformation();
    fFiledInfo.DisplayName = "Description";
    fFiledInfo.Type = WebReference.FieldType.Text;
    fFiledInfo.Value = "Ticket";
    WebReference.FieldInformation[] fFiledInfoArray = { fFiledInfo };
    FileStream strm = new FileStream(sourceUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] fileContents = new Byte[strm.Length];
    byte[] r = new Byte[strm.Length];
    int ia = strm.Read(fileContents, 0, Convert.ToInt32(strm.Length));
    strm.Close();
    uint copyresult = copyService.CopyIntoItems(sourceUrl, destinationUrl, fFiledInfoArray, fileContents, out cResultArray);
```

Please help me out in finding the exact issue.

Thanks
Sudheer

Comment: The code is actually trying to upload a local file to sharepoint site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `http://sp2010` is configured as  valid Sharepoint mapping in Sharepoint Central Administration Application Management & Configure Alternate Access Mappings.
You don't have it, but if URL has a port number, it should also be configured in SP AAM. 

**IMPORTANT! Don't use IP address in the service endpoint url.** 
This should work. I am doing the same from Java :).

Good luck,

Boris